# Scope of variable in DOJO when created from within function

Tags: javascript, dojo

In a DOJO widget there is code in the postCreate and destroy method to create/start and stop a timer like you can see below. Depending on the value in a drop down box the timer is started or stopped. This works fine so far.

```
postCreate: function() {

    var deferred = this.own(<...some action...>)[0];
    deferred.then(
        lang.hitch(this, function(result) {

            this.t = new dojox.timing.Timer(result.autoRefreshInterval * 1000);
            this.t.onTick = lang.hitch(this, function() {
                console.info("get new data");
            });
            this.t.onStart = function() {
                console.info("starting timer");
            };
            this.t.onStop = function() {
                console.info("timer stopped");
            };

        })
    );

    this.selectAutoRefresh.on("change", lang.hitch(this, function(value) {
        if (value == "Automatic") {
            this.t.start();
        } else {
            this.t.stop();
        }
    }));
},
```

When leaving the page the timer is still active so I want to stop it when I leave the page using DOJOs destroy() method.

```
destroy: function() {
    this.t.stop();
},
```

This however throws a `this.t.stop is not a function` exception. It seems like `this.t` is not created in the context of the widget although I use `lang.hitch(this...`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by just renaming the variable `t` to `refreshTimer`. Maybe `t` is some kind of reserved variable in Dojo?